# What is the difference between trace log and counter log?

Tags: performance, monitoring

In performance monitor, what is the difference between counter log and trace log? Any guidelines on when we should use each of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Counter logs** poll the event in some period interval (for e.g. every minutes) based on a setting, whereas **Trace logs** only log the event when something happens.